# OpenRasta - Encoding Errors as JSON rather than HTML

Tags: openrasta

I notice OpenRasta.Core has an HtmlErrorCodec which is responsible for rendering a the server error page sent out when a handler throws an Exception.

When I make an JSON Ajax request to an exception throwing handler this Codec is selected and the exception is rendered as HTML.

I have tried to register my own IMediaTypeWriter for IList<Error> with MediaType("application/json") so I can send back JSON to the browser, but it seems to be ignored.  Can anyone help?

Thanks
Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an error, indeed a codec with IList will be selected, but will follow the normal conneg for a type.

I'd suggest having a look at the request log and finding out how and why the html codec gets selected (I'd suspect with my remote debugging tunnel vision that you may have a browser sending the equivalent of `Accept: text/html,application/json`, at which point OR doesn't really know which of the two is acceptable, which is probably a bug as we register text/html with a q of 1 where it should be 0.5). If that's indeed what the problem is, the solution is to remove the registration for the html error codec, which you can do by providing your own DependencyRegistrar.

Comment: Yep, sorted!  Was a problem with the accept headers, had to mess around with JQuery. Also bumped up my codec to have q=1.0 just in case! Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

Can you just catch your exceptions, wrap them in a type and do something like:

```
ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType<MyErrorWrapper>().WithoutUri.AsJsonDataContract()
```

Comment: Yes that's possible, but I ideally want to make use of OpenRasta's internal Error handling which I think already by generates a resource of type IList<Error>